# Accessing fully developed dom through plugin in Firefox

Tags: dom, firefox-addon

I need to see the fully loaded and devloped dom of a page, i.e after my client loads up my page I want them to be able to click a button on fire fox and then fire fox will send me the fully developed dom so I can look through and see what happened there.
Can anyone help point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a function to know whether DOM is ready. A functionality provided by many Javascript frameworks, but [refer this](http://books.google.com/books?id=GgJN2CC_2s4C&lpg=PA90&ots=7x_fgZadNI&dq=domready%20techniques&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false) if you need a pure js implementation.
*When the DOM is ready the button is enabled for the user to click.*
Then you may have a function to serialize the DOM tree to a string. As Load and Save DOM is not yet implemented in Mozilla, read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) to get to know what you want.
Now you can send the Saved DOM to your Web Service.

```js
//Code grabbed mostly from MDN article linked
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "chrome://passwdmaker/content/people.xml", false); 
req.send(null);
var dom = req.responseXML;

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
              .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);   
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
         .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);//get profile folder  
file.append("extensions");   // extensions sub-directory
file.append("{5872365E-67D1-4AFD-9480-FD293BEBD20D}");//GUID of your extension
file.append("myXMLFile.xml");   // filename
foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0664, 0);//write, create, truncate
serializer.serializeToStream(dom, foStream, "");//remember, dom is the DOM tree
foStream.close();
```

Hope this would help!

Comment: Thanks man, I am goign to play with it and I will post back the full version :)